# Spring social instagram : cannot find current version

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I followed this tutorial https://jhipster.github.io/tips/012_tip_add_new_spring_social_connector.html to implement **instagram's** spring social in pom.xml, but here's the issues : the dependencies cannot find the current version. I figured this problem when I tried (as the tutorial told me to) to implement InstagramConnectionFactory. Indeed, the Java file cannot find the class, obviously because of the unfound version.

I also tried to get the version through the official spring-social-instagram repo : https://github.com/mattupstate/spring-social-instagram-example/blob/master/pom.xml but the version "1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT" (${org.springframework.social-version}) isn't correct either.

Has anyone ever gotten this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Maven can't resolve the dependency because spring-social-instagram is not available in Maven Central. You have to either [add a maven repository to your POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html) which provides spring-social-instagram or you have to [install it to your local repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).